# Axios returning garbage values

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fetch-api

Axios is returning weird garbage values, such as
`�2���ϫ��M@�~�II�{!`

I'm on a wsl2 ubuntu, node-version is v19.0, axios is 1.2.0

My code could not be easier:
`

```
const axios = require("axios");

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

fetch() is working like a charm. Any ideas or possible solutions?

Comment: Try importing axios default: `const axios = require("axios").default;`

Comment: I did that. The problem was the headers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### In v1.2.1 fixed this error.

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with `application/json` in axios.get header in v1.2.0

The default of it is `gzip`

This is demo code in  v1.2.0

```
const axios = require("axios");

const getUsers = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data, null, 4));
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getUsers();
```

Or your code style.

```
const axios = require("axios");

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    {
        headers: {
            'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

Result

```
$ node test.js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
    },
... removed
```

Comment: I have a similar problem however even after adding accept encoding it works at one place and other place still shows garbage value. Any workaround for that?

Comment: @TanishqVyas, using the latest [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) version (v1.6.3)